# NSTableView Custom Row View Caching

Tags: swift, scroll, nstableview

I've been customising my NSTableRowView using rowViewForRow, but this has led to a serious performance issue when scrolling as the rows are constantly redrawn.

I tried updating my code to only redraw if the row doesn't exist which gives much faster/smoother scrolling, but sometimes some views now display the wrong content.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, rowViewForRow row: Int) -> NSTableRowView? {

    let identifier = NSUserInterfaceItemIdentifier("MyTableRowView")

    var rowView = tableView.makeView(withIdentifier: identifier, owner: self) as? MyTableRowView

    // does the row exist?
    if rowView == nil {

        // create the row view
        rowView = MyTableRowView(frame: NSRect.zero)

        // set the identifier
        rowView?.identifier = identifier

    }

    return rowView

}
```

Any suggestions much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured this out. The function was working fine, but one of my custom button views required `setNeedsDisplay` on `isChecked` to update the display. This has previously always worked because the row had been redrawn all the time.